# Reactjs DOM-based open redirection

Tags: security, reactjs, react-router

I got this vulnerability after a scan on my website built with ReactJS.
The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based open redirection.

window.location.replace(window.location.pathname+window.location.search+"#"+e)

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think something is missing at the end of the line. Can you post that part (the full line of code)? It's very relevant to see what exactly makes its way into the new location.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?